# What's the best collation to use in MySQL for it to include spaces?

Tags: php, mysql, collation

So, I have this project, where a user can update a field, which works as intended.

The issues start when the user enters a space `' '` in the field.

For example, let's say the field was originally `test1`, and user changes it to `test 1`. This change takes place, and is printed as intended as well.

However, if the user goes ahead and inputs anything, from `test1` to  `test1` to whatever, the change doesn't take place at all. No matter what the user inputted.

I'm sensing it has something to do with the collation I use in the database, and no matter which one I used, the issue is still present, and, to be frank, I don't know much about collations to begin with.

The code that updates the field is simply:

```
   `$query = $pdo -> prepare("SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE field = ?");
    $query -> bindValue(1, $new_name);

    $query -> execute();
    $num = $query -> rowCount();

    if ($num == 0) {

        $query = $pdo -> prepare("UPDATE table SET table = ? WHERE table = ?");
        $query -> bindValue(1, $new_name);
        $query -> bindValue(2, $old_name);

        $query -> execute();
    }`
```

Does someone have have any input on my problem, either as to how's caused or how to fix it?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You are searching by field and updating by table?

Comment: That has nothing to do with collation. Spaces are still matching characters, so no matter what collation it is, `test 1`, `test1`, and ` test1` are all completely different strings. If you want to match the strings without spaces, then you're going to need to strip the spaces from both the value in the database and the value you're passing in.

Comment: This is NOT MySQL issue. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=26c44c5c77ac775977f93d9eaee72625 Check your client code/software.

Comment: @Grumpy 'field' is supposed to be a field inside the table `table`, that stores the value that the user inputs.

Comment: @aynber yeah, will probably do something like that and come back here to post the answer. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: _“the change doesn't take place at all”_ - how _exactly_ did you actually verify that?

Comment: @CBroe I print the value the user inputs, and it never changes after the user inputs something that has a space in it

Comment: @Marcel  5.7.23-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 - (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

- To see exactly what is stored in the column `col`, do `SELECT HEX(col) ...`  A space will show up as 20.
- To trim leading and trailing spaces entered in a `<form>` use PHP's `trim()` function.
- MySQL will ignore *trailing* spaces, depending on the datatype of the column.  Are you using `CHAR`, `VARCHAR`, `TEXT`, `BLOB`, or something else?
- Otherwise, leading and internal spaces are maintained by all parties involved.

  ```
    mysql> SELECT HEX("test 1");
    +---------------+
    | HEX("test 1") |
    +---------------+
    | 746573742031  |
    +---------------+
      t e s t   1
  ```